# http.get callback hangs

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to write a wrapper that lets me call an API using http.get. However, callback never seems to complete; it returns but then seems to block the event loop.

I have a dummy function below that removes the logic that builds my API url and just accepts a pre-built URL. If I run this in the repl, I'll never get back to the prompt, the body of the page will be printed and then just sit there.

```
function Request(url, callback){
    var data = '';
    http.get(url, function(res){
        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            data += chunk.toString();
        });
        res.on('end', function(){
            var obj = data;
            callback(obj);
        });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Got error " + e.message);
    });
}
```

Any advice or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. I'm running v0.8.15.

Comment: Do you have an example usage or URL you can include? The code provided seems to work fine with `Request('http://stackoverflow.com', ...)`, at least. One possibility is a conflict with response encoding used by the server, as Node's `Buffer` [only supports a few encodings](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) and [default is `utf8`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end).

Comment: Odd. For me, when I run that code in the repl, I never get back to a prompt. So I can't run another command. I never explicitly .end() the request. Is that why the loop isn't closing? Though even when I tried that, it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: ...maybe this is just user error actually. If I hit 'enter' in the repl, I get to my new line. I'm definitely not hanging in the event loop, I was able to do three requests in a for loop.